# How do I dynamically calculate a water bill cost using my usage volume and volume-to-cost brackets?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to predict my water bill using a flowmeter connected to my mainline.

I have the price rates used for my bill which are:
27.54kL @ $2.392
91.80kL @ $3.413
300.00kL @ $3.699

So for example, if I used 250kL, my bill would be broken down as:

```
1st rate: There are more than 27.54kL in 250kL, so cost of this rate is: 27.54*$2.392 = $65.88 (250 - 27.54 = 222.46kL remaining for the next rate)
2nd rate: There are more than 91.80kL in 222.46kL, so cost of this rate is = 91.80*$3.413 = $313.31 (222.46 - 91.80 = 130.66kL remaining for next rate)
3rd rate: There are less than 300kL in 130.66kL, but more than 0, so cost of this rate is: 130.66*$3.699 = $483.31 (130.66 - 130.66 = 0L remaining for next rate (if there was a 4th))

Total = sum of all rate costs = $862.50
```

How can I calculate this in a dynamic way, so that if the rates or even the number of rates change, it still works? I can easily reproduce the above, but I'd like to use lists and list comprehension or other loops to produce the final cost.

This will calculate what I need, but it's not dynamic:

```
volumeCostDict = [[27.54,2.392], [91.80,3.413], [350.00,3.699]]
volume = 271 # kilolitres

rate1Volume = volumeCostDict[0][0] if volume > volumeCostDict[0][0] else volume
rate1Cost = rate1Volume * volumeCostDict[0][1]

rate2Volume = volumeCostDict[1][0] if volume > (volumeCostDict[0][0] + volumeCostDict[1][0]) else volume - volumeCostDict[0][0]
rate2Cost = rate2Volume * volumeCostDict[1][1]

rate3Volume = volumeCostDict[2][0] if volume > (volumeCostDict[0][0] + volumeCostDict[1][0] + volumeCostDict[2][0]) else volume - volumeCostDict[0][0] - volumeCostDict[1][0]
rate3Cost = rate3Volume * volumeCostDict[2][1]

print(rate1Cost)
print(rate2Cost)
print(rate3Cost)

totalCost = rate1Cost + rate2Cost + rate3Cost
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have to find the correlation between how much water is used and how much price has increased first. then you should define conditions resulting in an increase in the price should water usage rise above a certain level. start by finding and defining the correlation first

Comment: I added more info to the cost breakdown which should hopefully help. I know the correlation between usage and cost, using the rate brackets. I just don't know a simple loop-based way to calculate it out given the brackets

Comment: thats not going to help you. let me put it this way... you have to have the exact percentage increase of price from one level to the other. suppose the price for each kl in level one is n. what is the same for level 2? n + (n*0.2)?? and what is the same for level 3 and so on. you have to have a fixed number / formula for the price. what you have done is put the price in manually. what if there are infinite levels?? for example level 50 usage? what then? come up with the increase formula first. then it'll be easy.

Comment: @Applez00800 What happens when the price is `still more than 300` in the `3rd rate`? Cos following up this, will give you `$862.50` every time, if the usage is like `400`, `4000`, `2000` etc?

Comment: @Alok Technically, there is another rate but I haven't found it yet, however I don't expect my water usage to so above this. I will however, when I find it, add it into the rates array.

Comment: @Mahdi_J I don't want to need to calculate a formula, as that's not what I'm given in my water bill. I'm given the rate brackets that define the volume-to-cost brackets. If these change in the future, I just want to update the rates array and not have to calculate anything else

Comment: Also, I've edited my question further by including the code that will calculate what i'm looking for. I just need help to convert this into using loops to calculate the same thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, just needed to code it statically first and then work out the pattern to apply it dynamically. There's still probably a simpler way, but this works
EDIT: to work for all cases

```
volumeCostDict = [[27.54,2.392], [91.80,3.413], [350.00,3.699]]
volume = 271 # kilolitres

rateVolumes = [volume_kL \
                 if volume_kL < volumeCostDict[i][0] and i == 0 \
                 else volumeCostDict[i][0] \
                 if volume_kL > sum([volumeCostDict[j][0] for j in range(i+1)]) \
                 else volume_kL - sum([volumeCostDict[k][0] for k in range(i)]) \
                 if (volume_kL - sum([volumeCostDict[k][0] for k in range(i)])) > 0 \
                 else 0 \
                 for i in range(len(volumeCostDict))]
totalCost = sum([rateVolumes[i]*volumeCostDict[i][1] for i in range(len(rateVolumes))])
print(rateVolumes)
print(totalCost)
```

Comment: Hey, check out my answer. I just attempted in order to give you the desirable result. Your answer is good too. Just adding more to your bucket :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way out, if you say that, the range would be same, it is only data change thing. So what we can do, we can make use of `while` loop and follow this algo

```
1. While volume != 0
2. Two extreme cases and two normal cases are there:
   a) {If the volume becomes less the least value `volumeCostDict[0][0]`} and {If volume > `volumeCostDict[0][0]` and volume > `volumeCostDict[0][0]`}
   b) {If volume >= `volumeCostDict[0][0]`} and {If volume >= `volumeCostDict[1][0]`}
3. Deal with the both the cases, in case one do the computation for both the extreme cases. 
4. For normal cases, computation is there, which you have shown already
5. Print after coming from the while loop
```

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
volumeCostDict = [[27.54,2.392], [91.80,3.413], [350.00,3.699]]
volume = 250 # kilolitres
totalCost = 0

# this will run until volume becomes 0
while volume != 0 :
    # extreme case, what if the value becomes less than the least
    # in our case 27.54, so we calculate the same for 27.54
    # and make the value go to 0 
    # this is required, since for Volume = 200, you won't get any result
    if volume < volumeCostDict[0][0]:
        totalCost += (volume * volumeCostDict[0][1])
        volume = 0
      
    # this is normal case, which will check if the volume is
    # greater than equals least value  
    if volume >= volumeCostDict[0][0]:
        volume -= volumeCostDict[0][0]
        totalCost += (volumeCostDict[0][0] * volumeCostDict[0][1])
        
    # this is normal case, which will check if the volume is
    # greater than equals second rate value 
    if volume >= volumeCostDict[1][0]:
        volume -= volumeCostDict[1][0]
        totalCost += (volumeCostDict[1][0] * volumeCostDict[1][1])
      
    # extreme case again, if the volume after deduction  is still 
    # greater than the normal cases, that is 27.54 and 91.80
    if volume > volumeCostDict[0][0] and volume > volumeCostDict[1][0]:
        totalCost += (volume * volumeCostDict[2][1])
        volume = 0

print("${:.2f}".format(totalCost))
```

```
# OUTPUT for volume = 250 will be 
>>> $862.50
```

You can check this with other `volumes` as well. I know this solution will sound layman to you. But tell me how much useful it was for you :) For any suggestions, I am open to learn.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your time in working this out :) I appreciate your answer

Comment: No problem @Applez00800, I liked that question, it is unique. Fun indeed. All the best :)